# ServerSocket with single client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I have written below code to create a simple ServerSocket with constant operation which sends commands to a single client while reading data from a database. If the client exits and reconnects (always with different remote port) server keeps sending commands to the previous "instance". How can i differentiate current client from the one who disconnected in order to make sure that the data will be delivered to him. Could you please also make any recommendations?

```
public class Server {

    private static final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?serverTimezone=Europe/Athens";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(50001);
        System.out.println("[SERVER 50001] Waiting for client connection...");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "test", "1234")) {

            String selectCommandSql = "SELECT `id`, `command` FROM `commands` WHERE (`is_sent` = 0 OR `is_sent` = NULL) LIMIT 0,1";

            while (true) {

                try {

                    Socket client = listener.accept();
                    System.out.println("[SERVER 50001] Connected to client: " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

                    while (true) {

                        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectCommandSql);
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                        if (rs.next()) {

                            int id = rs.getInt("id");
                            String command = rs.getString("command");

                            out.println(command);

                            String updateCommandStatusSql = "UPDATE `commands` SET `is_sent` = 1, `sent_at` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
                            PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(updateCommandStatusSql);
                            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                            ps2.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(now));
                            ps2.setInt(2, id);

                            int success = ps2.executeUpdate();

                            if (success > 0 && command.equals("exit")) {

                                if (ps2 != null) ps2.close();

                                if (rs != null) rs.close();
                                if (ps != null) ps.close();

                                if (out != null) out.close();
                                client.close();
                                break;

                            }
                        }

                        if (rs != null) rs.close();
                        if (ps != null) ps.close();
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }

                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            listener.close();
            System.out.println("[SERVER 50001] Server closed.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PrintWriter simply swallows IOExceptions so your server likely won't notice when the output stream was closed. You should probably use `!client.isClosed()` or `client.isOutputShutdown()` as loop condition (though I have not tested it so please test it yourself)

Comment: @Marcono1234 Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check if your client is properly closing socket before exiting, check if you have `socket.close()` under `finally` in client.

Comment: Please post your client code as well to help others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Liju there is no problem when the client closes socket properly when exiting. It only happens if client drops unexpectedly before client socket closes. Server is not able to recognize the broken connection in this case.

Comment: @talex "*TCP doesn't support detection of broken connection*" - actually, it does, if you turn on TCP keep-alives (ie `client.setKeepAlive(true)`). If a keep-alive probe fails, the connection becomes invalidated and will report errors to the app. And if the client disconnects gracefully, that will absolutely be reported to the app.

Comment: @talex And if the application keeps sending, as this one does, and peer host crashs or the peer exits or the cable is pulled or anything else happens that stops the data being acknowledged, an `IOException: connection reset` will be thrown. Please don't post misinformation or guesswork here.

Comment: @Marcono1234 You're right about `PrintWriter` swallowing exceptions, but neither `isClosed()` nor isOutputSHutdown()` will detect this condition. The correct solution is either `PrintWriter.checkError()` or not using `PrintWriter` at all: use a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @Liju `public class Client {

    private static String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static int SERVER_PORT = 50001;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP,SERVER_PORT);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String serverCommand = inputLine;
            System.out.println("Command received from server:" + inputLine);

        }
    }
}`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tried your suggested solution but it still doesn't work properly. I added `client.setKeepAlive(true);` after accepting the client and `if (out.checkError()) { out.close(); client.close(); System.out.println("Client disconnected."); break; }` into the next loop.

Comment: This is what happens as of now.                                                                                         `Waiting for client connection...
Connected to client: /127.0.0.1:41338
Sent: aaa -> /127.0.0.1:41338
Connected to client: /127.0.0.1:41345`                                                                  Client (41338) is connected and drops unexpectedly. When he reconnects (41345) and i try to message him, the message goes to the previous instance (41338) and then the server seems to understand that a new client (41345) is connected. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: 'Message goes to the previous instance' is impossible unless the previous instance is still running and connected. What is your evidence for this assertion?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Client: /127.0.0.1:41345 is connected to my Server. There is a loop waiting for a command to be sent to the client. Meanwhile the client drops unexpectedly before receiving the command and reconnects after a few seconds. He has a new port now /127.0.0.1:41338. If i send a command at this point, it will be sent to /127.0.0.1:41345 because Server hasn't notified that the first client was dropped.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne i found a solution! When trying to in.readLine() from client , if the client is not connected it throws a SocketException which i can handle properly. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: "If i send a command at this point, it will be sent to /127.0.0.1:41345". No it won't. This is not an observation but a guess.